# Break table in HTML

Tags: html, asp-classic, vbscript

I've several records in a table. And if I want to ensure that there will only be 3 columns in a row, no matter the number of records .

I have used the following. But the problem is I have more than one record in record1.

The following is the result but I want it to be the 2nd example.

```
0378                0378
Ms. Mary Jane           Ms. Jane Smith          
SCHOOL (SCIENCE)                SCHOOL (SCIENCE)
CLASS: Class1           CLASS: Class2
BUNDLE: 1                   BUNDLE: 2

ABC: 41             FGH: 1
                        FGH: 1


JKL: 2              0378
                        Mr. David O'Conner
                        SCHOOL (SCIENCE)
                        CLASS: Class3
                        BUNDLE: 3

                        ORE: 42
```

2nd Example where JKL is still on the 1st row.

```
0378                0378
Ms. Mary Jane           Ms. Jane Smith          
SCHOOL (SCIENCE)                SCHOOL (SCIENCE)
CLASS: Class1           CLASS: Class2
BUNDLE: 1                   BUNDLE: 2

ABC: 41             FGH: 1
                        FGH: 1
                        JKL: 2

0378
Mr. David O'Conner
SCHOOL (SCIENCE)
CLASS: Class3
ISSUE: 01-2012 ISSUE
BUNDLE: 3

ORE: 42
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the Modulo operator:

```
Response.Write "<table width=""100%"">"
r = 0
Do Until objRS.EOF
    myData = objRS("myfield")
    If (r Mod 3)=0 Then
        If r>0 Then
            Response.Write "</tr>"
        End If
        Response.Write "<tr width= ""354"">"
    End If
    Response.Write "<td>" & myData & "</td>"
    r = r + 1
    objRS.MoveNext
Loop
objRS.Close
If r>0 Then
    Response.Write "</tr>"
End If
Response.Write "</table>"
```

This will show three columns of data.

Comment: As is r is equal to one record and I'm tryin to get two or more records group together. it will break at the 3rd record but I want it to break when there are three classes and not three product

Comment: Sorry not sure what you mean. Got example?

Comment: I have changed the code above. After the 3rd record, it will break to the next row. But I have 2 or more records that make into one "main" record. I want 3 "main" records in a row.

Comment: Sorry I still can't see the logic here. Are you hard coding the desired position of every record? What makes `JKL` special so it should be in the first row?

Comment: JKL is in the Class2 but it is also the 4th record so it has break down to the 2nd row. I wanted all the Class2 records to be displayed first before it will break into the 3rd row. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe what you need is two separate queries, for each "Class" - might make things much more simple..

Answer (score 0):

not sure what diferentiates records by column but I think you are looking for something like this:

```
  response.write"<table width=""100%"">"
  response.write"<tr width= ""354"">" 

  response.write"<td>" 
      response.write"<table>"
      for i= 1 to [flag to stop column1]
      response.write"<tr>" 
      response.write"<td>"    
      response.write"Record" & i & ":" & record(i)
      response.write"</td>" 
      response.write"</tr>"
      next
      response.write"</table>"
  response.write"</td>" 

  response.write"<td>" 
      response.write"<table>"
      for i= 1 to [flag to stop column2]
      response.write"<tr>" 
      response.write"<td>"    
      response.write"Record" & i & ":" & record(i)
      response.write"</td>" 
      response.write"</tr>"
      next
      response.write"</table>"
  response.write"</td>" 

  response.write"<td>" 
      response.write"<table>"
      for i= 1 to [flag to stop column3]
      response.write"<tr>" 
      response.write"<td>"    
      response.write"Record" & i & ":" & record(i)
      response.write"</td>" 
      response.write"</tr>"
      next
      response.write"</table>"
  response.write"</td>"

  response.write"</tr>"
  response.write"</table>"
```